# wxErlang error message

Tags: erlang, wxerlang

I cannot get wxErlang to work at all.  Do i need to include a module.  Can't find any basic information relating to it.  Please help.  I am look for a very basic example of a module.

the error I am getting is

undefined function wx:start/0

Comment: it seems that wx:start with 0 parameters doesn't exists... maybe it takes some parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to include the wx lib using the following line

```
-include_lib("include/wx.hrl").
```

include/ is a sub directory in my project containing the wx library.

Comment: Note: It should be: -include_lib("wx/include/wx.hrl"). Right?

Comment: I am on a windows box and have setup my application on a different drive.  I added and include directory and placed the wx files in that, so it works in my situation.

Answer (score 4):

This should display an empty frame:

```
1> wx:new().
{wx_ref,0,wx,[]}

2> Frame = wxFrame:new(wx:null(), 0, "myFrame").
{wx_ref,36,wxFrame,[]}

3> wxFrame:show(Frame).
true
```

Comment: OK I am getting "bad function wx:new()." i am guessing I am missing a library.  How do I go about solving that?

Comment: Are you using R13? Did you compile with wx support?
I think the library dependencies are: freeglut3-dev and libwxgtk2.8-dev

Comment: You must also enable SMP support for wx.

Comment: unfortunatly atm i am on a windows box.  I have just searched through the erl/lib directory and did not find wxerlang.  I have now downloaded the latest release of erlang and seems that I now have the wxerlang lib.  I have another problem now, but I will look into it before posting another question.

Comment: I have plucked the following code from some tutorial but I think it must be very old could you confirm this and point me in the right direction if possible.

-module(test).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    wx:start(),
    XRC = wx:xml_resource_get(),
    wx:init_all_handlers(XRC),
    wx:load(XRC, "gui.xrc"),
    Frame = wx:load_frame(XRC, ?NULL, "frame_1"),
    wx:show(Frame).

Comment: I think that is for an old version of wxerlang.sourceforge.net

Comment: I have the standard install of erl 5.7.1 on Windows and Zed's script above certainly shows a window. I did no builds - simply downloaded the standard windows install...

Comment: M:\>"c:\Program Files\erl5.7.1\bin\erl.exe"
Eshell V5.7.1  (abort with ^G)
1> wx:new().
{wx_ref,0,wx,[]}
2> Frame = wxFrame:new(wx:null(), 0, "myFrame").
{wx_ref,35,wxFrame,[]}
3> wxFrame:show(Frame).
true
4>

Comment: Your erlang install should have a lib\wx-VER\examples directory containing some examples

Answer (score 1):

To find the ex-erlang-samples You should issue the following call in EShell to locate the base directory for wx-erlang:

> code:lib_dir(wx).

On Windows the returned path uses "/" instead of "\", so just replace them.

Inside that directory there shoud be a directory "examples". Start with "simple" inside those examples.

Also You should check if wx is working properly: use

> wx:demo().

in EShell.